# Afinal, o PH ainda hoje tem som de F?

Tags: ortografia, pronúncia, acordo-ortográfico

Pelo que pesquisei, o dígrafo *ph* foi abolido do Português com a [Reforma Ortográfica de 1911](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reforma_Ortogr%C3%A1fica_de_1911#Principais_altera.C3.A7.C3.B5es) e substituído pelo *f*. No entanto, (pelo menos no Brasil) ainda se pronuncia o *ph* com som de *f*, ao menos ao referenciar marcas/produtos de uso corrente. Cito como exemplo: *iPhone* (telefone celular), *Philips* (marca de eletrônicos) e *Phebo* (marca de sabonetes), todos pronunciados com *f* no lugar do *Ph*.

Até aqui, Ok, são nomes estrangeiros, cuja pronúncia original parece ser o *f*, no entanto, existe no Brasil o *[Instituto do Patrimônio Histórico e Artístico Nacional](http://portal.iphan.gov.br/)*, cuja sigla é *IPHAN* e sempre que ouço alguém pronunciar sua sigla ela é dita como *ifân*, novamente com som de *f* ao invés do *ph*.

Pergunto, existem exemplos semelhantes em Portugal de uso do *ph* com som de *f*? Está correta a pronúcia *ifân* para a sigla *IPHAN*?

Comment: Em Portugal também pronunciamos *ph* como *f* em marcas como *iPhone*.

Comment: As palavras com ph sofreram a transformação e passaram a usar f, assim, as palavras originais em nomes ou escritas em livros antigos vão continuar com som de f pois não podem receber "correção".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Existem 63 palavras com *ph* em português: http://www.palavras.net/search.php?m=ph&d=17, e ainda assim muitas são estrangeiras.

Em relação a pronúncia, como nativo afirmo que não está errado. É comum o som de *f* para *ph* em siglas.

Comment: Ótima referência! Mas de todas as 63 palavras lá listadas só reconheci 1 como não sendo um nome próprio de origem estrangeira. _Anopheles_, o mosquito transmissor da malária é chamado de a-nó-_fê_-les no Brasil. Mais uma para a lista de palavras com ph pronunciadas como f!

Comment: @gmauch  "anopheles" é um termo científico para o mosquito-prego em pt-BR,  ("anofeles"  ou "melga" em pt-PT).   "Anopheles" descreve um gênero que possui várias espécies.  Toda a taxonomia que classifica os seres vivos, animais e vegetais, uni ou pluricelulares, foi feita em Latim, de modo que um chinês, um angolano ou um canadiano possam todos usar o mesmo nome para os mesmos seres.  O gênero "anopheles"  possui vários sub-gêneros, como o Anopheles Lophopodomyia, que também usa o "ph".  O mesmo se aplica a todas as bactérias, vírus, fungos e metazoários: usa-se o "ph" em lugar do "f"